# Set koComputed only on load and save

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two knockout variables 'Frequency' and 'FrequencyText' which is simply the text description associated with the Frequency.

In my model I have:

```
    self.Frequency = ko.observable();
    self.FrequencyText = ko.computed(function () {
    var description;
    switch (self.Frequency()) {
        case "1":
            description = "Once";
            break;
        case "2":
            description = "Twice";
            break;
        case "3":
            description = "Three Times";
            break;
        default:
            description = "";
            break;
        }
       return description;
    }, this); 

  //Ajax call
  GetAjax.done(function (data) {
        self.Frequency(data.Frequency);
  });
```

The Frequency is loaded by Ajax and the FrequencyText moves with it. But then if the user changes their Frequency using radio buttons the Text changes too, I only want this to change when the Frequency is saved to the profile. So I want to set it on page load, and again if they save any changes. To do this I can change it to something like this:

```
self.Frequency = ko.observable();
self.FrequencyText = ko.observable();


 GetAjax.done(function (data) {
        self.Frequency(data.Frequency);
        self.FrequencyText(ko.computed(function () {
        var description;
             switch (self.Frequency()) {
             case "1":
                 description = "Once";
                 break;
             case "2":
                 description = "Twice";
                 break;
             case "3":
                 description = "Three Times";
                 break;
             default:
                 description = "";
                 break;
           }
           return description;
           }, this)); 
  });
```

So that it is only set from the Json data (so on load) but then Id have to repeat all that code pretty much in the function that saves the new frequency.

I tried to leave the ko.computed function out of the ajax like the first example and simply pass it a parameter on load and on submit to update it like:

```
   self.FrequencyText = ko.computed(function (newFrequency) {
         //switch logic
    });
```

But it said I would have to use a write: statement to use params. And that is the point where I got too confused and came here. Any help on how to clean this up a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case I would not use a computed, but an observable which is updated manually by a standard function.

```
self.Frequency = ko.observable();
self.FrequencyText = ko.observable("");

GetAjax.done(function (data) {
    self.Frequency(data.Frequency);
    self.UpdateFrequencyText(data.Frequency);
});

self.UpdateFrequencyText = function(frequency){
    var description;
    switch (frequency) {
        case "1":
            description = "Once";
            break;
        case "2":
            description = "Twice";
            break;
        case "3":
            description = "Three Times";
            break;
        default:
            description = "";
            break;
    }
    self.FrequencyText(description);   
}
```

Comment: Ah but of course, thats what I get for trying to overuse Knockout, thanks